# How to stop random color from repeating?

Tags: javascript, css

the title changes color randomly when clicked but it repeates the same color often **(I don't want it to repeat the same color in the array twice in a row)**. I tried to fix this with an if statement but im not sure why it didn't work.

```js
var title = document.querySelector(".title");

function changeColor() {
  let newArray = ["DarkSalmon", "LightSalmon", "Crimson", "Red",
    "DeepPink", "YellowGreen", "GhostWhite"
  ];
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() *
    Math.floor(newArray.length - 1));
  console.log(random);
  if (title.style.color !== newArray[random]) {
    title.style.color = newArray[random];
  }

}

title.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
```

```html
<h1 class='title'>Berserk</h1>
```

Comment: Give us HTML code, it might help us answer you.

Comment: The only way to be sure a color doesn't get repeated is to either remember what colors have been used, or at least remove used colors from the list of choices in the future.

Comment: @Scott Hunter I just don't want it to repeat in the same color twice

Comment: @Mugs does it has to be those colors on the array or it could any random colors?

Comment: @ManuelAbascal my end goal is any random color but I thought trying it with just an array of colors would be an easier first project

Comment: Using *any* random color means you can get colors which are *technically* different but look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If don't want colors to get repeated in a row, you could just add an `else` statement to your `if` statement.

**I found the error!** It's in the capitalization of your color names... Change them to all lowercase and it will magically

```js
var title = document.querySelector(".title");

function changeColor() {
  let newArray = ["darksalmon", "lightsalmon", "crimson", "red", "deeppink", "yellowgreen", "ghostwhite"];
  let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(newArray.length - 1));
  if (title.style.color != newArray[random]) {
    title.style.color = newArray[random];
    console.log(title.style.color);
  } else {
    changeColor();
  }
}

title.addEventListener("click", changeColor);
```

```html
<h1 class='title'>Berserk</h1>
```

Comment: And once all of the colors have been chosen once?

Comment: Well, you see, the person asking the question said that the colors shouldn't be repeated. So essentially, at one point all colors get chosen and just stay on the last color chosen.

Comment: @rojo so sorry man I mean't I don't want the same color to be repeated twice in a row. Let me edit that

Comment: @Rojo I love it, and it 100% seems like it would work but i'm still getting repeat colors. It's as if the condition isn't working? Which makes no sense... ugh >.<

Comment: @Mugs I found the error - it's the capitalization of your color names, they're supposed to all lowercase :)

Comment: @Rojo haha I was just commenting that same thing. Thanks so much for the help. Your the best :p

Answer (score 1):

This will let each color be selected exactly once. Once all colors have been used, the list is refreshed so all colors can be randomly selected again, and so on.

```js
// Identifies header element & defines initial colors array and colors array
const header = document.getElementsByClassName("title")[0];
const initialColors = ["DarkSalmon", "LightSalmon", "Crimson", "Red", "DeepPink", "YellowGreen"];
let colors = [];

// Calls `changeColor` when the header is clicked
header.addEventListener("click", changeColor);


// Defines the `changeColor` function
function changeColor(){

  // Remembers the most recent color (formatted as lower-case)
  let previousColor = header.style.color.toLowerCase();

  // Makes all colors available whenever no colors are left (including on first click)
  if(colors.length === 0){

    // Copies the `initialColors` array, and returns the copy
    // (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
    colors = initialColors.slice();
  }
  
  // Cuts a random color out of the colors array
  let newColor = removeRandFrom(colors);

  // If removed color happens to match previous color, forces an additional change
  // (Can only ever happen immediately after the `colors` array has been replenished)
  if(newColor === previousColor){
    newColor = removeRandFrom(colors);
  }

  // Sets text color to whichever color was just randomly removed
  header.style.color = newColor;
}


// Defines the `removeRandFrom` helper function
function removeRandFrom(arr){
  
  // Gets a psuedo-random number
  const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

  // Removes and returns the element at the randomly selected index
  // (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
  return arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

```html
<h1 class='title'>Berserk</h1>
```

References:
  [MDN - slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)
  [MDN - splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Comment: Very interesting answer to a slightly different question. This is honestly a better way to do the color selection with random colors and your use of function compositions is on point. Thanks so much for the awesome code.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the color would repeat and your `if` statement prevents that from happening, nothing else happens, either. So the effect is the same as a repeating color.

Instead of the `if` statement, you could use a `ẁhile` loop to randomly select new colors until you have one that is different from the current.

```
let random;

do {
   random = Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(newArray.length - 1));
} while (title.style.color === newArray[random]);

title.style.color = newArray[random];
```

Comment: I think that is creating an infinite loop because I tried it and after I click the page bugs out xd

Comment: @Mugs oops, is has to be `===`, not `!==`.

Comment: okay now its working but no different then my old one, it still repeats colors :( I checked with a console.log(newArray[random]) right before title.style.color = newArray[random];

Comment: @Mugs that's because the array gets recreated each time the function is called. See my answer for a better explanation.

Comment: A better approach would be to remove the current color *before* a random color is chosen from the array.

Comment: @Rojo it's definitely wasteful to create the array in the function but the array values are the same every time regardless so it's not making a difference whether its on the inside or out

Comment: @Mugs well at first when I thought you didn't want the colors to ever repeat, so the code I created required the array to change.

Comment: @Rojo yeah that was totally my fault for not being clear sorry man. But your correction did work when not wanting any color to repeat. So appreciate that, thank you.